# How to pass eventData arguments to .on() using .trigger() method in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such an event handler on `<select>` element:

```
select.on("change", null, {
    tbody: $("#tbody"),
    colspan: 5,
    onLoad: onLoadHandler,
}, onSelectChange);
```

And in `onSelectChange` I get them this way, through `event.data` object:

```
event.data.tbody,
event.data.colspan,
event.data.onLoad
```

In other place of my code I want to trigger `.on("change")` event of my `select` element and I need to provide the same parameters:

```
select.trigger("change", [$("#tbody"),  5, onLoadHandler]); // <- how to pass them as event.data?
```

My question is how may I pass these parameters to `trigger` so that I can use them the same way in `onSelectChange` handler:

```
event.data.tbody,
event.data.colspan,
event.data.onLoad
```

Comment: That data is coming from where the event is ***bound***, you can't place data there when triggering. When triggering, all you can do is create ***additional*** parameters, for example `function myHandler (event,additionalParams) {...`

Comment: @KevinB, I read the documentation, I'm asking if there is some workaround

Comment: No, there isn't. but that's too short to be a useful answer.

Comment: Nope, the data property of the event object can't be modified by .trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change the handler if you want to be able to do this.  In your handler, instead of just using `event.data`, use something that either pulls from `event.data` or from the additional parameters:

```
function onSelectChange(event, triggeredData)
{
    var data = triggeredData || event.data;
    // do stuff with data.tbody or whatever here
}
select.on("change", null, {
    tbody: $("#tbody"),
    colspan: 5,
    onLoad: onLoadHandler,
}, onSelectChange);
```

Then you can send different data in with trigger:

```
select.trigger("change", {tbody:$("#tbody"), colspan:5, onLoad:onLoadHandler});
```

or use `event.data` when the event is triggered by user action.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change event.data, but you can use additional parameters as people say.
Or you can pass event parameters:

```
select.on('change', function(event) { console.log(event.tbody, event.colspan, event.onLoad) })
select.trigger({type:'change', tbody:'val', colspan:'val', onLoad:'val'})
```

BTW, it's bad practice to call a function by triggering an event.